# Parsing a JSON file

Tags: ios, xcode, json

How can I parse a file of this kind:

```
{"group":"1"}{"group":"2"}{"group":"3"}
```

Usually I parse in this way:

```
NSString *fileContent = [[NSString alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:reloadPath];  

SBJsonParser *parser = [[SBJsonParser alloc] init];

NSDictionary *data = (NSDictionary *) [parser objectWithString:fileContent error:nil];  

// getting the data from inside of "menu"  

//NSString *message = (NSString *) [data objectForKey:@"message"];
//NSString *name = (NSString *) [data objectForKey:@"name"];

NSArray *messagearray = [data objectForKey:@"message"];
NSArray *namearray    = [data objectForKey:@"name"];


NSDictionary* Dictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:messagearray forKeys:namearray];
```

...objects of this king...

```
{"message":["Besth"],"name":["thgh"]}
```

...but in the type I want to parse, which is the key and object??

By the way I want to retrieve a list like this: 1, 2, 3, ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not valid JSON. You can validate for example at: http://jsonlint.com

You could rewrite it as valid JSON like so:

```
{
    "some_groups": [
        {
            "group": "1"
        },
        {
            "group": "2"
        },
        {
            "group": "3"
        }
    ]
}
```

Then you could extract the data by doing something like this:

```
NSArray *groups = [data objectForKey:@"some_groups"];

for (NSDictionary *group in groups) {
    NSLog(@"group number: %@", [group valueForKey:@"group"]);
}
```

Comment: so using objective c how can I make something like that

Comment: I've updated my answer with an example. Note that I have not run my code.